# Can I fit a coccoro combi car seat on an Uppa Baby stroller cruz?

Tags: car-seat

My son outgrew huge Uppa car seat so we bought a Combi. Can I fit that on my stroller?

Or am I going to have to buy another stroller?

Comment: What does the manufacuturer say? Welcome to the site!

Comment: Is this on-topic? This is what old-timey SE called "too localized", but that reason is no longer a valid VTC

Comment: Stephie, the manufacturer doesn't say anything about it. And thanks for welcoming me here. I use stackexchange sites a lot for tech, but never tried it for parenting before.

Comment: Sounds like you already have the seat and the stroller. Have you tried just putting the seat on the stroller? It should fit snugly and securely and at an appropriate angle.

Comment: @SeanHenderson I don't have it. I ended up buying a different setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. You will need another stroller.  With safety being the number one priority of these products, do not attempt to modify these products to make them fit with equipment other than the intended system.